# Hartshorne Exercise II 9.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In exercise 9.1 he gives a statement:

Set $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $X=\mathbb P_k^n$, and $Y$ be a connected, nonsingular, positively dimensional subvariety of $X$, then $\Gamma(\hat X,\mathcal O_{\hat X})=k$.($\hat X$ is the completion of $X$ along $Y$)

Then exercise 9.2 asks us to use this result to prove:

> Let $Y$ and $X$ be as above, and let $f:X\to Z$ be a morphism of $k$-varieties. Suppose $f(Y)$ is a single closed point $P\in Z$. Then $f(X)=P$ also.

I don't know how to get this result. Set $i=f|_Y$, then I have thought that we can get a map from $\mathcal O_Z$ to $i_*(\mathcal O_{\hat X})$ by passing to the inverse limit. But then what can I do? Could you give some hints? I'm confused about how to understand $f(X)$ through the formal scheme...

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: [Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896228/116766) on this site asks about this exercise, which may help.